# cannot rsync permission protected files

Tags: permissions, rsync

I've to use rsync to transfer folder to the backup periodically(basically want to automate this). Initially i've to enter password everytime but i got this working by adopting public/private key authentication mechanism.

But what is happening is it can easily send files to the back without using sudo and neither prompting for password input, except the files which are permission protected. for them it says: `rsync: send_files failed to open "/home/usr/...../checkpoints/246/descriptors.json": Permission denied (13) .`

So for them i've to use `sudo` and enter the password. How can i solve this? folders are periodically added to a common directory for transmission, say a period of 50ms. So i need to have automation in this.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, either configure `root` to use the ssh key that you created, or change the permissions of the files so that you can read them as your non-root user.

#### Option 1: use ssh key as root

Because you are root, you can just read and use the ssh private key that you created for your user.  `ssh` lets you specify the private key with the `-i` flag, and rsync lets you change the remote shell command with the `-e` flag.  So you'd end up with a command that looks something like this:

```
sudo rsync -e "ssh -i /home/usr/.ssh/id_rsa" <the rest of your rsync args>
```

Replace `/home/usr/.ssh/id_rsa` with the actual path to the ssh key you created.  I assume that your ssh key is not protected by a passphrase.  If it is, you'll need to remove the passphrase with `ssh-keygen -p <keyfile>`.

#### Option 2: change the permissions on the source files

The cleanest solution may be to fix whatever's writing the files so that they are owned by your non-root user in the first place.  But you could also `chown` the files before you copy.  E.g.,

```
sudo chown -R "$USER" "/home/usr/...../checkpoints"
```

But be aware that there's a race condition.  New files created as a different user before the rsync is completed may give you an error and won't be copied until the next run.